# Parse string data from serial port to integer

Tags: c#, parsing, arduino

I am sending serial data from an Arduino Nano (analog input from a potentiometer) to a C# program. It displays fine on the console but I need to use the numbers to control a joystick through vJoy. I need to convert the string (for example "932") to an integer. I can't simply use `int.Parse(string)` since it says:

> Input string was not in correct format.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    _serialPort = new SerialPort();
    _serialPort.PortName = "COM9";
    _serialPort.BaudRate = 9600;
    _serialPort.Open();

    while (true)
    {
      string a = _serialPort.ReadExisting();
      Console.Write(a);
    }
}
```

It seems that it sends a new line command on every pass since using `Console.Write` is on a new line. If we could strip entirely the string then maybe the parsing would work.

Comment: Can you check if your string is really "932" when doing int.Parse? Because it should work without problems. Maybe try Trim https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trim(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Also ensure that there is no whitespace, Try `Console.WriteLine($"'{a}'");` and see if there's anything other than just a number between the single quotes

Comment: I feel like you should introduce some message framing. Maybe add a termination character to the end of the strings you send so you know when you've received the whole message.

Comment: @Afonso In the console it surely is just "932" or whatever value the sensor sends(between 0 and 1023).Here is a snippet of the console.https://imgur.com/a/BwSR3Q8

Comment: @Jaxi Using your command i get some weird artifacts on the output.Maybe due to the speed of reading and writing.Here is a pic https://imgur.com/a/XAK5XZj

Comment: Like I said, add a termination character so you know when you've received the whole message.

Comment: @AlexTselikas this shows that the data you're returning isn't just a number, it's multiple numbers that all need processing seperately

Comment: @AlexTselikas look into binding to an event too, rather than doing a while true loop: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Jaxi Thanks for the tip!Just implemented it.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to convert a `string` to `int`. `int.Parse` is one of them, but like `Convert.ToInt32`, it raises an exception if your string is not a numeric

To avoid the exception, you can use `TryParse`

The `TryParse` method is like the `Parse` or `Convert.ToInt32` method, except the `TryParse` method does not throw an exception if the conversion fails.

Do not forget to clean up your string

```
int portNum = 0;
string yourPortStringFormatted = Regex.Replace(yourPortString , @"\t|\n|\r", "");
bool isSuccees= Int32.TryParse(string.IsNullOrEmpty(yourPortStringFormatted) ? "0" : yourPortStringFormatted , out portNum );
```

Comment: Note that you can write `int.TryParse(yourPortString, out var portNum)` since C# 6

Comment: @aloisdg Thanks for the useful info

Comment: I tried TryParse,the  boolean is always false meaning it can't succeed in the conversion.

Comment: @AlexTselikas and so? my answer is about avoiding the exception while converting a string to numeric. If it continues to return ``false``, that means your string isn't a numeric and you must check why you have that case. If you exepect a function to convert "abc" to "123", it exists never in the programmation....

Comment: @ThierryV that's what i am trying to find out.In the console it clearly outputs an integer value(from 0 to 1023) but it doesn't let me convert it to an int.I suspect it also sends formatting characters like \n or \r .

Comment: @ThierryV Interesting...Using your code,the conversions works only when the sensor value is 0,after that the conversion fails.

Comment: @AlexTselikas So that means your string must be like "12b3". Good luck, only you who can debug and find down the value returned. I updated the answer to handle the case string.Empty

Comment: @AlexTselikas Maybe your string is empty, look at the answer updated.

Comment: @AlexTselikas Why do you refuse to add a termination character to the data you're sending? This would have resolved all of these problems you keep bringing up.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem.The arduino was sending the serial data too fast.Adding a delay(100); at the end of the loop fixed the problem.

Comment: Nice!! Glad to hear that